# closed database in Navicat

Tags: database, navicat

I've connected to my database server using Navicat Premium and I can find my database in custom database list but I can't do anything on my db as it's shown "closed" and when I right click and select open database noting happens. I googled a lot but I didn't anything to help me ! 
so if anyone has a tip to help me I'll appreciate in advance. 
thanks 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjRsb.png)

Answer (score 0):

No idea ????
No one has no solution ? 
No answer !?

:|